# AutoAlign Checkboxes in row using angular material design

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using angular material design for my angular application, I am getting the fields of an index of elasic search and creating them as checkboxes in my form.
It is getting generated, but when it has more than 4 fields, the alignment looks clumsy.

**HTML:**

```
 <div layout="row" layout-align='left start'>                       
   <md-checkbox   ng-repeat="field in selectedFields"    layout="row"  ng-click="toggleCheck(field)"    style="text-transform:capitalize"  aria-label={{field.name}}>
   {{field.name}}
  </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

[`Plnker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vs61ks2CEueRGHrNMWub):

Comment: make a fiddle for this.

Comment: @nitin i have attached the plunker with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked angular-material-layout.css and found "layout-wrap".

You need this :

```
 <md-content class="md-whiteframe-z2">
            <div layout="row" layout-wrap  md-scroll-y flex>
                   <md-checkbox flex='20'
                  ng-repeat="field in fields"
               layout="row"
               ng-click="toggleCheck(field)"
               style="text-transform:capitalize"
               aria-label={{field}}>
               {{field}}
                </md-checkbox>
            </div>
</md-content>
```

Working here : [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOKGgQyFw65m9UgH2ioC?p=preview)

Comment: it will only stick to the alignment u specify in "layout".  You can do a repeat with only 4 or 5 checkboxes in each row.

Comment: i guess link is out dated.  No checkboxes seen